# Plot only out-degree of network-graph

Tags: r, igraph

I have an igraph object:

```
d <- graph(sapply(1:16, function(i) {
  rbind(i, ((i+1):(i+3)-1) %% 16 + 1)
}))
```

I would like to plot only the out going edges of this graph using `plot()`

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: your question title is missleading by the way, do you want to plot the network-graph of the outgoing-edges or do you want to plot the degree-distribution???

Comment: I want to plot the network-graph

Comment: Whats wrong with `plot(d)`?

Comment: he just wants to plot the outgoing-edges, excluding the incoming ones, which is impossible given that it depends on the perspective: the edge 1->12 is an incoming edge for 12 and an outgoing one for 1....

Comment: each node has 6 lines going in our out. What I woudl like to is a graph that has 3 lines each. I guess that is not possible. But I haven't been able to generate a lattice where each node has exactly 3 connections (in our out)

Comment: I still dont understand what you want, if you want to ignore the direction just try `as.undirected(d)` this way there is no "double-counting" or extra-counting for ingoing and outgoing edges

Comment: so you could just do `plot(as.undirected(d))`

Comment: I just want a circular graph where each node has exactly 3 edges

Comment: something like this? `plot(graph.lattice(6,circular=T) + edges(c(1,5),c(2,4),c(3,6)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the out-degree using `degree.distribution` using the following R code:

```
plot(degree.distribution(d,mode="out"))
```